# XSLT: select either of siblings

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

> XML Input

```
<skills>
    <skill>
        <id>123</id>
        <name>Java</name>
    </skill>
    <skill>
        <id>123</id>
        <name>Java</name>
        <employee>John Doe</employee>
    </skill>
</skills>
```

Both are skill nodes and always have same values for **id** and **name** nodes, but difference is one of them has extra text node **employee**.
**They could be present in any order.**
First skill node will always be present. In some cases, second skill node could be present as well.
If only first skill node is present, select/print that. But if a skill node with **employee** is present, select/print that. Output is CSV.

> Output

**either**

```
id | name | employee
1 | Java |
```

**or**

```
id | name | employee
1 | Java | John Doe
```

Can xslt be written for transformation?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: But can there be more than the two `skill` elements, for other `id`/`name` combinations as well? Sounds like a grouping problem in XSLT 2 best tackled with `for-each-group`.

Comment: No. Its always same id/name. Thanks for the grouping idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're after, so I have guessed.

Try the following (I haven't dealt with line feeds). It's not the prettiest way to do it, but I think it provides what you want. Basically, it's just matching all the `skill` elements that don't have an `employee` sub-element, and then for each, if there are matching `skill` element(s) with and `employee` sub-element, print them instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/skills/skill[not(employee)]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="skill">
  <xsl:param name="employee" select="/skills/skill[id=current()/id and name=current()/name and employee]" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count($employee) > 0">
      <xsl:for-each select="$employee">
        <xsl:value-of select="id" /> | <xsl:value-of select="name" /> | <xsl:value-of select="employee" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="id" /> | <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great - you should accept the answer then or other people will keep answering.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a grouping problem to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="' | '"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="skills">
      <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(skill/*/local-name())" separator="{$sep}"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="skill" composite="yes" group-by="id, name">
          <xsl:value-of select="id, name, (current-group()/employee)[1]" separator="{$sep}"/>
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 3 online sample at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTZ, if you are restricted to XSLT 2 use `<xsl:for-each-group select="skill" group-by="string-join((id, name), $sep)">` instead of `<xsl:for-each-group select="skill" composite="yes" group-by="id, name">`.